# Prevent processing data multiple times in Woocommerce thankyou hook

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, woocommerce

I have code that sends the order data to an external delivery service, creating a new order there. I noticed that if you reload the "Thank you" page, the code will work again and send the same information. Result: several identical orders are created in the support service. What should I add to the code so that this does not happen?

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_to_delivery');
function send_order_to_delivery( $order_id ){
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $order_data = $order->get_data();

    $order_id = $order_data['id'];

    // Send data
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.example.com/api/index.php?new_order");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $decoded = (array) json_decode($result);

    // Output
    if( isset($decoded['result']) && $decoded['result'] == 'success' && isset($decoded['order_id']) && !empty($decoded['order_id']) ){
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'delivery_order_id', esc_attr( $decoded['order_id'] ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Thanks for the description of the problem. But the decision was not found unfortunately...

Comment: That is exactly what you need to do to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following, where we check if some value exist already in the order meta data for `'delivery_order_id'` `meta_key`, avoiding executing this task twice or more:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_to_delivery');
function send_order_to_delivery( $order_id ){
    // Checking if this has already been done avoiding reload
    if( get_post_meta( $order_id, 'delivery_order_id', true ) ) 
        return; // Exit if already processed

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order_data = $order->get_data();

    $order_id = $order_data['id'];

    // Send data
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.example.com/api/index.php?new_order");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $decoded = (array) json_decode($result);

    // Output
    if( isset($decoded['result']) && $decoded['result'] == 'success' && isset($decoded['order_id']) && !empty($decoded['order_id']) ){
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'delivery_order_id', esc_attr( $decoded['order_id'] ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should solve your problem definitively.